# How can I get a user's entire media history from the Instagram API?

Tags: ruby, instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

I'm using the [Instagram ruby gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) to try to import my entire Instagram post history. I'm able to get my 20 most recent posts using the `user_recent_media` method and I'm expecting the response object to also give me pagination info with a `next_url` that I can call to get the next 20 posts. Instead, `response.pagination` returns `{}`.

I tried passing in the id of the last post returned as the `max_id` of the next call to `user_recent_media` and I get no data in response.

I also tried making the same API call manually using `HTTParty` instead of the gem and the pagination info was still empty, so I don't think it's an issue with the gem.

I know there are definitely more than those 20 posts in my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instagram's new API Sandbox](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) is likely limiting your access to even your own posts. While in the sandbox:

> Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from
>   each of those users.

Instagram has shifted their focus to advertising applications of their API and has made the development of independent applications dramatically more onerous, if possible at all.

If you manage to make it through the [approval process](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/), you can try [generating a new access token](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) with the appropriate grant type.